# What's the difference between Stability and a Stun-break?

Tags: guild-wars-2

As an Elementalist, my primary source of both Stability and stun-breaks is [[Armor of Earth]](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armor_of_Earth). As this is the only class that I play, I feel I have some misconceptions about what **Stability** is and what a **stun-break** is.

So far, I believe that Stability is capable of preventing **Immobilization**. However, stun-breaks cannot remove Immobilization. This leads me to believe that there may be more differences in the  the capabilities and usage of Stability and stun-breaks.

What kind of differences are there between Stability and stun-break? When is it best to use either and what kinds of things are they vulnerable to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break-stun is to use after you were touched by a control effect in order to remove it, whereas stability will prevent incoming control effects for X seconds, but won't remove those already in place.

Break stun :

> Skills that stun break will cancel control effects such as stun. These are often indicated by a "Breaks stun" skill fact on the tooltip. Certain traits will also break stun by granting stability upon being hit by a control effect. Stun breaks work on control effects which last for a duration. Fear is considered a control effect as well as a condition and can be broken.

Stability :

> Stability is a boon that protects against control effects.
>   Unlike a stun breaker, it does not remove effects that are already in place, although many skills granting stability will also remove stuns. Stability stacks in duration up to 3 times.

And this is the list of control effects it protects from :

> Cannot be knocked down, pushed back, pulled, launched, stunned, dazed, floated, sunk, or feared.

ps : You just had to click on "stability" and "break-stun" on the link you gave for your armor of earth to find those informations.

Comment: Just for reference, http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armor_of_Earth

Comment: What about the special case of **Immobilize** (stability works, stun break does not)? Is that the only special case?

Comment: Immobilization is not a special case :
http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Immobilized
Immobilization is a condition, not a control effect, therefore it is not affected by stability or break-stuns, but instead you have to use condition removal.

Comment: Ah. I think my confusion was [Fear](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fear), not Immobilization. "Fear is notable in that it **also counts as a control effect**, meaning it can be cleared by both condition removal as well as stun breaks." I thought Immobilization was the special case, but Fear is the special case.

Comment: I always give questions about two days to encourage alternate answers.